# How can I fix parallax images causing whitespace at bottom of page?

Tags: css, parallax

I'm making a website for myself as practice. I'm attempting to have a parallax banner then content below that but for some reason I need to set the minimum height of the inner content to be at least the same size as the banner itself, otherwise you can scroll past the end of the inner content and see the parallax images that are supposed to be hidden. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I could fix it? I tried inspecting the page and the space at the bottom seems to just be the background and not any parallax layers. The background is fixed and set to 100% so I'm not sure why that would cause this behavior.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="scrollContainer" class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__group">
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--0">

        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--1">

        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--2">

        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--3">

        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--banner">

        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--4">

        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--5">

        </div>
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--6">

        </div>
        <div id="parBody" class="parallaxBody">
            <div id="circleContainer" class="container topSec">
                <div id="smallCircle" class="smCircle1"></div>
                <div class="smCircle2"></div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    html{
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    font: 50% / 1.5 Arial;
    font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    height: 100%;
}

/*parallax styles for 1000px width
Do something different for less than 1000px width*/

  .parallax__group {
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
  }

  .parallaxBody{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(25, 25, 75);
    background-size: 1300px auto;
    top: 1800px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }

.parallax {
    background-image: url("../images/layer1.png");
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: 0;
    background-size: 1300px 1300px;
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    font-size: 200%;

    
  }
 .parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: -12px;
    background-size: 1300px 1300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .parallax__layer--6 {
    top:-100px;
    height: 3200px; /*adjust for screen sizes*/
    background-size: 1300px 3200px;
    background-image: url("../images/layer7.png");
  }
  .parallax__layer--5 {
    top:-200px;
    height: 2000px;
    background-size: 1300px 1500px;
    transform: translateZ(-0.5px) scale(1.5);
    background-image: url("../images/layer6.png");
  }
  .parallax__layer--4 {
    top:-200px;
    height: 1200px;
    transform: translateZ(-1.5px) scale(2.5);
    background-image: url("../images/layer5.png");
    background-size: 1300px 1300px;
  }
  .parallax__layer--3 {
    top: -200px;
    height: 1200px;
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
    background-size: 1300px 1300px;
    background-image: url("../images/layer4.png");
  }
  .parallax__layer--banner {
    height: 300px;
    background-size: 50vw 15vw;
    left: 32%;
    top: 400px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-32%, -70%);
    transform: translate(-32%, -70%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    background-image: url("../images/banner.png");
  }
  
  .parallax__layer--2 {
    top: -500px;
    height: 1200px;
    transform: translateZ(-4px) scale(5);
    background-size: 1300px 1300px;
    background-image: url("../images/layer3.png");
  }
  .parallax__layer--1 {
    top: -400px;
    height: 1000px;
    transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(6); /*Try moving z-index up and scaling down*/
    background-image: url("../images/layer2.png");
    background-size: 1300px 1300px;
  }
  
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 1300px){
    .parallax__layer--6 {
      top:-200px;
      height: 3400px;
      background-size: 1600px 4200px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--5 {
      top:-500px;
      height: 2200px;
      background-size: 1600px 2000px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--4 {
      top:-200px;
      height: 1500px;
      background-size: 1600px 1600px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--3 {
      top: -200px;
      height: 1500px;
      background-size: 1600px 1600px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--banner {
      height: 300px;
      background-size: 50vw 15vw;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .parallax__layer--2 {
      top: -700px;
      background-size: 1600px 1600px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--1 {
      top: -1200px;
      height: 1200px;
      background-size: 1600px 1600px;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1600px){
    .parallax__layer--6 {
      top:-200px;
      height: 2000px;
      background-size: 2000px 5000px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--5 {
      top:-700px;
      height: 3000px;
      background-size: 2000px 2500px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--4 {
      top:-400px;
      height: 1800px;
      background-size: 2000px 2000px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--3 {
      top: -700px;
      height: 1500px;
      background-size: 2000px 2000px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--banner {
      height: 300px;
      background-size: 50vw 15vw;
      top: 0;
      left: 12vw;
    }
    
    .parallax__layer--2 {
      top: -1000px;
      background-size: 2000px 2000px;
      height: 1300px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--1 {
      top: -1000px;
      height: 1300px;
      background-size: 2000px 2000px;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 2000px){
    .parallax__layer--6 {
      top:-800px;
      height: 5000px;
      background-size: 2600px 6500px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--5 {
      top:-1300px;
      height: 4000px;
      background-size: 2600px 3250px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--4 {
      top:-1100px;
      height: 2200px;
      background-size: 2600px 2600px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--3 {
      top: -1100px;
      height: 2400px;
      background-size: 2600px 2600px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--banner {
      height: 500px;
      background-size: 35vw 10vw;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    .parallax__layer--2 {
      top: -2500px;
      background-size: 2600px 2600px;
      height: 1800px;
    }
    .parallax__layer--1 {
      top: -2000px;
      height: 1500px;
      background-size: 2600px 2600px;
    }
  }
  
 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you put absolute URL for images into the CSS and then you/I/we can turn this into a working example using the `snippet` tool. Cheers

Comment: Margin 0 on both html and body. Let me know if that helps, if yes it shall be a duplicate and I’ll refer you to the proper Q/A.